# Missing forms from Submit History report in CommCare when the filter is set to "today"

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to see forms that I am currently submitting in CommCare via live preview and mobile device. I have the date filter on the Submit History report to today. Is there a reason my forms might not be showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The today date filter for this report on CommCare defaults to Eastern Standard Time. Therefore if you are in a time zone that puts you in a different day than the eastern coast of the United States, the default filter of "today" won't show your form submissions. For instance, if you are submitting forms at 7am in Cape Town and looking for them to show up in your Submit History report filtered to today, you won't see those submissions because the filter for "today" is technically referring to "yesterday" for your timezone.